# HTML5 Canvas, replacing colors in an image not working on some machines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a 2d RTS HTML5 / Javascript game. I use images to display the player's units and buildings. I provide the image and then use a script to replace certain colors in the images with other color, to get different versions of an image with different colors (so the soldier of player 1 has a red sword and the soldier of player 2 has a blue sword and so on...).
The problem is, for maybe ~20% of the users this replacing thing doesnt work and they see all units in the same (default) color. Im now wondering why this is. Heres the function i use to replayce the colors:

```
// returns a image with some colors replaced, specified by search and replace, which are arrays of color arrays ([[255, 255, 255], [...], ...], )
ImageTransformer.replaceColors = function(img, search, replace)
{
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    canv.height = img.height;
    canv.width = img.width
    var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4)
        for(var k = 0; k < search.length; k++)
            if(imgData.data[i] == search[k][0] && imgData.data[i + 1] == search[k][1] && imgData.data[i + 2] == search[k][2])
            {
                imgData.data[i] = replace[k][0];
                imgData.data[i + 1] = replace[k][1];
                imgData.data[i + 2] = replace[k][2];
            }

    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    return canv;
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this library](https://github.com/greggman/imageutils/blob/master/dist/imageutils.js). I use it for exactly the same reasons, to make multiple colors of players. It also has the ability to limit the range of the colors affected so for example you can adjust only the purple part of the original image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers may or may not apply a gamma to the image prior to drawing them, the intent is to have more natural colors (...).
I bet this is the Browsers which apply a gama that fool your algorithm.

Rather than test for strict equality, you might use a color distance, and decide of a threshold to decide wether to switch or not :

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
var data = imgData.data, length = imgData.data.length ;

    for(var k = 0; k < search.length; k++) {
       var thisCol = search[k];
       for(var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
            var colDist = Math.abs(data[i] - thisCol[0] ) 
                          + Math.abs(data[i+1] - thisCol[1] ) 
                            + Math.abs(data[i+2] - thisCol[2] );
            if( colDist < 5 )
           {
              data[i] = thisCol[0];
              data[i + 1] = thisCol[1];
              data[i + 2] = thisCol[2];
           }
     }
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

return canv;
```

---

(here i used as distance the sum of absolute differences in between r,g,b ; as @MarkE suggest, you can choose others, euclidian being this:

```
        var colDist = sq(data[i] - thisCol[0] ) 
                      + sq(data[i+1] - thisCol[1] ) 
                        + sq(data[i+2] - thisCol[2] );
       // notice this is the squared euclidian distance.
       // whith function sq(x) { return x*x }
```

test several pictures / distances, and see what fits.

test several threshold also.
).

Comment: Good answer.  Just suggesting an enhancement: The RGB color space is more Euclidian rather than Linear.  You might enhance your answer by calculating Euclidian distance between the sample and the search colors.

Comment: You're quite right, even if rgb is no 'that much' euclidian ( :-) if mathematicians are reading this, hope they won't die from it). Edited.

Comment: If this is true you might consider using WebGL as WebGL has the option to require browsers not to apply gamma correction nor any other color space adjustments.

Comment: Maybe: var diffR=imgData.data[i]-search[k][0]; var diffG=imgData.data[i+1]-search[k][1]; var diffB=imgData.data[i+2]-search[k][2]; var euclideanDelta=Math.sqrt(diffR*diffR+diffG*diffG+diffB*diffB); if(euclideanDelta<yourTolerance){//replace}

Comment: @markE : as you know, when comparing an euclidian distance to a threshold, you've much better done by comparing sq()+sq()+sq() to sq(threshold) rather than using sqrt, quite costly. Other than that, performance diff between yours/the suggested code must not be high.

Comment: In production I usually leave off the Math.sqrt and compare the squared values (saving 1 Math.sqrt): diffR*diffR+diffG*diffG+diffB*diffB < yourTolerance*yourTolerance.  I just offer the Math.sqrt version because it helps users understand where the math is coming from :-)